# Will the Minium Stone work with the Automatic Crafting Table?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Using an automatic cobblestone generator and an Automatic Crafting Table (ACT). I will pipe the cobblestone into the ACT that has a Minium Stone in place, and hopefully it will output dirt, which in theory I could keep repeating to produce clay or sand or any other block I need. Would the ACT even work with the Minium Stone? Would this setup work at all? If not, is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work, but have another one in an adjacent chest or inventory, otherwise it will not craft.

Comment: The durability of the one in the chest will decrease, by the way, not the one in the crafting interface.

Comment: @Jochem Interesting, did not know that.